# How do I capture a ship?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

I teleported to an enemy ship, killed all the crew I found, and then returned to my own ship, but the game didn't reward me with anything.  I thought perhaps my scrap would increase after I jumped away, but it didn't.  What must I do to recover resources from a captured ship once the crew is dead?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There's a chance that the ship you boarded had a Cloning Bay, in which case it needs to be destroyed for the crew to be considered fully dead. If that's not the case, you said you killed "all the crew you found", which makes me think you do not have improved sensors to see the inside of enemy ships. In that case, it's possible that you simply missed some crewmembers.

Comment: Yes, assuming it isn't a drone ship (or the final boss) killing the crew (and destroying the cloning bay if one is present) *should* bring up a standard rewards window (usually with higher rewards than a destroyed ship.

Comment: @ʇsәɹoɈ Yes, as soon as the last enemy dies, you get a popup about how you search and strip the ship of anything useful. If the ship had some breaches, it's possible that a survivor might've been locked away in some remote room, or maybe they were trying to repair some system you didn't check.

Comment: Although I did not have improved sensors, having walked the entire enemy ship and then waited for a few minutes with no enemies attacking or repairing anything, it seems unlikely that I missed someone. I'm just going to assume there was a cloning bay, since I wasn't looking for one of those. I have taken a few ships since then, so at least now I know how it's supposed to work. Thanks, all.